# i18n.dir() don't change when I stock it in var or let

Tags: react-native, i18next

I try to change style depend to direction of langage

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
let isAR = i18n.dir();
```

I `console.warn(isAR)` and it doesn't change but when I `console.warn( i18n.dir())`
directly without isAR variable it changes everytime I click on FRENCH/ARAB button:
this is my code:

```
console.warn( isAR + ' ' + i18n.dir());
```

this is what I have:

[image]

normally I must have `rtl rtl` or `ltr ltr`
I tried to change `let isAR` to `var isAR` or `const isAR`
but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Since you only assign it once, it won't change automatically on language change. You should reassign it on language change or use the `i18n.dir()` directly.

Comment: how to assign it on language change ?
ps. it worked nice like that but I dont change anything

Comment: well, just write isAR = i18n.dir(); again. But I'd recommend just using i18n.dir() directly without a variable not to get confused. If your intention is to check for Arabic language, you can create a function: function isAR() { return i18n.dir() == 'rtl'; }. The function will be "auto-updated" since it'll query dir() value on each call.

Comment: it doesn't work:
import i18n from 'i18next';



 _isAR = () => {
    return i18n.dir() == 'rtl';
 }


export default Styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.main,
  },

  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: _isAR() === 'rtl' ? '#fff' : 'red',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },

});

Comment: that's because you're only checking it once in styles. You should check it in your  on each render in your render() method. You should also make sure the components re-renders on language change.

Comment: but style doen't change

Comment: I had see it in this tutorial, 11min :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2vaocDlg-s